# Twilio JS Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, twilio

I am currently using the [Python helper](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Js library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js) for [Twilio](http://twilio.com). I am having a hard time determining how I can I be able to determine if my user is online or not. I know a function for js library containing about **Twilio.Device.presence**. It was successfully showing all the online user. But how can I determine if the user I am calling currently is online?

In the field number is where I am going to call:

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"
  placeholder="Enter a phone number or client to call"/>
```

In this function:

```
Twilio.Device.presence(function (pres) {
    if (pres.available) {
        // create an item for the client that became available
        $("<li>", {id: pres.from, text: pres.from}).click(function () {
            $("#number").val(pres.from);
            call();
        }).prependTo("#people");
    } else {
        // find the item by client name and remove it
        $("#" + pres.from).remove();
    }
});
```

The `pres.from` is the user that are online. How can I be able to for loop on it and check if the data in the `number` field is same.
Or how can I pass from the function to my views?.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

A simple way to do this would be to remove the click handler from the `<li>` element when you detect that the *available* property of a client has changed to false.  That way your users would not be able to initiate a call to that client.

You could also visually show the client state by altering the elements style based on the value of the *available* property.

Another option would be to remove the entire `<li>` when the client goes offline so users would not even see the client name.

If you want to keep track of both all online and offline clients, then I think you will need to keep some state on the client that tracks a list of online/offline clients.  A simple way to do this would be to use an array of client names.  As clients come online you can add their name to this array and as they go offline you remove them from the array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample for it? And is there a way I can track it in views.py file? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I actually want to intend to be able to use it in the backend part, because I am planning to use it as an API type. Because based on my research, you cant be able to use the `device.presence` in the views part.